# C++: Why does this basic 2D Quickhull algorithm return points in the incorrect order?

Tags: c++, algorithm, 2d, convex

The following is a C++ implementation of a 2D Quickhull algorithm for Convex Hulls taken from geeksforgeeks.org: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quickhull-algorithm-convex-hull/

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

// iPair is integer pairs 
#define iPair pair<int, int> 

// Stores the result (points of convex hull) 
set<iPair> hull; 

// Returns the side of point p with respect to line 
// joining points p1 and p2. 
int findSide(iPair p1, iPair p2, iPair p) 
{ 
    int val = (p.second - p1.second) * (p2.first - p1.first) - 
              (p2.second - p1.second) * (p.first - p1.first); 

    if (val > 0) 
        return 1; 
    if (val < 0) 
        return -1; 
    return 0; 
} 

// returns a value proportional to the distance 
// between the point p and the line joining the 
// points p1 and p2 
int lineDist(iPair p1, iPair p2, iPair p) 
{ 
    return abs ((p.second - p1.second) * (p2.first - p1.first) - 
               (p2.second - p1.second) * (p.first - p1.first)); 
} 

// End points of line L are p1 and p2.  side can have value 
// 1 or -1 specifying each of the parts made by the line L 
void quickHull(iPair a[], int n, iPair p1, iPair p2, int side) 
{ 
    int ind = -1; 
    int max_dist = 0; 

    // finding the point with maximum distance 
    // from L and also on the specified side of L. 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        int temp = lineDist(p1, p2, a[i]); 
        if (findSide(p1, p2, a[i]) == side && temp > max_dist) 
        { 
            ind = i; 
            max_dist = temp; 
        } 
    } 

    // If no point is found, add the end points 
    // of L to the convex hull. 
    if (ind == -1) 
    { 
        hull.insert(p1); 
        hull.insert(p2); 
        return; 
    } 

    // Recur for the two parts divided by a[ind] 
    quickHull(a, n, a[ind], p1, -findSide(a[ind], p1, p2)); 
    quickHull(a, n, a[ind], p2, -findSide(a[ind], p2, p1)); 
} 

void printHull(iPair a[], int n) 
{ 
    // a[i].second -> y-coordinate of the ith point 
    if (n < 3) 
    { 
        cout << "Convex hull not possible\n"; 
        return; 
    } 

    // Finding the point with minimum and 
    // maximum x-coordinate 
    int min_x = 0, max_x = 0; 
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        if (a[i].first < a[min_x].first) 
            min_x = i; 
        if (a[i].first > a[max_x].first) 
            max_x = i; 
    } 

    // Recursively find convex hull points on 
    // one side of line joining a[min_x] and 
    // a[max_x] 
    quickHull(a, n, a[min_x], a[max_x], 1); 

    // Recursively find convex hull points on 
    // other side of line joining a[min_x] and 
    // a[max_x] 
    quickHull(a, n, a[min_x], a[max_x], -1); 

    cout << "The points in Convex Hull are:\n"; 
    while (!hull.empty()) 
    { 
        cout << "(" <<( *hull.begin()).first << ", "
             << (*hull.begin()).second << ") "; 
        hull.erase(hull.begin()); 
    } 
} 

// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    iPair a[] = {{0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 4}, 
               {0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}}; 
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); 
    printHull(a, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Running the program unmodified with the given set of points returns (0, 0) (0, 3) (3, 1) (4, 4) in that order. Plotting according to the output results in something that looks like this:

[image: convex hull incorrect solution]

*Note that the line through the middle does not actually hit those three points*, it's just that the program I used to graph them drew the line right through them. If I'm not mistaken the correct order for the output should be more along the lines of (0, 0) (0, 3) (4, 4) (3, 1). Drawing them in this order would give you a genuine convex hull.

As I said, the following was a direct copy-paste of an implementation from geeksforgeeks. The project I'm working on requires convex hulls with *significantly* more points that are input from a file, and I've adapted the above to work in that format. That said, there seems to be a fundamental issue with the base algorithm, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated. Be really careful with `#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;`. It turns your code into a identifier collision minefield. If you find code like this in a tutorial seriously consider finding a different tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm adds the endpoints of L to the convex hull only when there are no points outside the line (i.e. the line is one of the edges of the hull). So the points are not added in order. Also, we check for all points in the starting of the quickHull function. So this code is not optimal. You can find a better implementation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull#Pseudocode_for_2D_set_of_points).